# Condition on unitary operator for real eigenstates of Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, observables, unitarity

I'm working with the discrete-time quantum walk in which the evolution is described by the unitary operator -

$$U = S(C\otimes I)$$
where $C$ is the coin operator (acts on spin degree of freedom of particle) described by $SU(2)$ rotation, and $S$ is shift operator given by

$$S = \sum_x \left[ |x+1\rangle \langle x|\otimes |\uparrow\rangle \langle \uparrow | +|x-1\rangle \langle x|\otimes |\downarrow\rangle \langle \downarrow |  \right]$$
Although, this description may not be necessary for what it follows. The Hamiltonian associated with this unitary given by

$$U = \exp(-iH) \rightarrow H =i \log(U)$$

I'm looking for a condition that I can put on $U$ so that $H$ has real eigenvectors or eigenstates. I think if $H$ is a real hermitian matrix, then, of course, it should have real eigenstates. But I'm not sure what condition to impose on $U$ (or choice of $C$).

Comment: By “real eigenstate”, do you mean that the eigenstate in the $x$-basis is real?

Comment: @Prahar Yes! I mean, real eigenstate in the $x$-basis.

Comment: The $\log$ Is a multivalued function, so there are many choices. I would say that if $U$ is real and sufficiently close to the identity the log defined by the series should be real, which is what you want.

Comment: Also, MSE seems a better place for this post

Comment: @Icv I can't put the condition that $U$ closer to identity consider the form of $U$.